# How to replicate an unparseable date error in Android?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

Crashlytics is reporting the following error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.android/com.myapp.android.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid date string: Unparseable date: "afaabhaieac`GMT+00:00" (at offset 0)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2465)
```

It's likely that the crash was on a device whose language/locale was not English/US-centric. Changing the language on my device or a virtual device doesn't throw the error. Is there a better way to replicate the error, given I don't actually know what is causing it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know for what language it was crashing it might be a tricky one to reproduce. What you could do instead is put the parsing of the date in a `try/catch` block and in the `catch` log a more specific message to Crashlytics using `Crashlytics.log(int priority, String tag, String msg);`. You could for example log the devices Locale and language settings or anything you think might be useful.

For more information about loggin in Crashlytics see their [docs](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html)

Comment: Yeah, I think this would work except that the error is in production, so pushing out a build to log an error seems like a kind of un-elegant way to attempt to solve this.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately Crashlytics doesn't log this information about devices by default as far as I know. I think your best bet is to dive into the details of each individual crash (click "View all sessions"), see what device is causing it and what OS version it's running and trying as many Locales by hand as you can. Would still suggest to add some custom logging in future releases